# how to kill js function in another function's scope

Tags: javascript, ajax

i built the `please wait` gif animator for my form submission, because the registration takes a bit more time.

now everything works fine, but my gif animation still keeps running even after success message. Thus my animation function is still running. how can i kill that function?

this is what i did now:

```
function loadSubmit(){
  ProgressImage = document.getElementById('progress_image');
  document.getElementById("progress").style.visibility = "visible";
  setTimeout("ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src",100);
  return true;
}
```

and i call this before my ajax function:

```
 loadSubmit();
 $.ajax({
   url: "/register_me/",
   type: "POST",
   ...
 }).done(function(){
      // can i somehow kill loadSubmit() function in this scope? 
 });
```

this would be so good to be able to do it..

thanks a lot

Comment: Why can't you just do this - `document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "none";`

Comment: um, hide the image in the callback? is it really that hard?

Comment: What is `setTimeout("ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src",100);` supposed to do, exactly? Passing a string to `setTimeout` seems strange to begin with (I didn't know you could do that), and besides that the string contains code that looks like a no-op.

Comment: @epascarello, yeaaah. sorry for dumbness, i totally misthought. :(.

Comment: @Celada you can pass string to setTimeout. SetTimeout evals that string after the desired interval. Though I agree that the code is a no-op

Comment: @Celada: I love your "I didn't know you could do that" comment!!! It gives me hope that a newer generation of js programmers are learning the right things. Way back in 1999 (and up to several years ago) most js programmers didn't know you can pass functions to setTimeout and you will see horrible js with code stored in strings requiring really awkward backslash-escapes to get the quoting right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setTimeout returns a integer value which can then be used to clear that timeout using the function clearTimeout

```
function loadSubmit(){
   ProgressImage = document.getElementById('progress_image');
   document.getElementById("progress").style.visibility = "visible";
   // what exactly you want you achieve through this timeout
   return setTimeout("ProgressImage.src = ProgressImage.src",100);

}

var intervalID = loadSubmit();
$.ajax({
  url: "/register_me/",
  type: "POST",
  ...
}).done(function(){
   document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "none"; //EDIT
   clearTimeout(intervalID)
});
```

Read the documentation for setTimout at MDN 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

EDIT: I misread the question. you need to hide the ProgressImage to hide the gif, you still need to clear the timeout.

Comment: great, very nice. thank you. i just show and hide the gif, thats it. i dont need even js function for it basically. now working like a charm! :). Many thanks

Comment: I am not sure whether it will make a difference. AFAIK javascript is single threaded and the timeout events are added to the event queue and when you clear the timeout after hiding the img or before hiding the img, the event will be removed from the queue as well. Please enlighten me if I am wrong.